# What exercises can I do to grow my lower abs at the gym?

Tags: muscle-gain, abdominals

I'm going to the gym and nowadays the only exercise I do for my abs is by using the abs machine with weights but I can see only the upper part of my abs grow.

What kind of exercises can I do for the lower abs?

Comment: There is no distinct lower abs muscle. It's all the same muscle and any exercise that works the upper half of the rectus abdominis muscle will equally work the lower half too. The only explanation for why you aren't noticing the lower half of your abs is that you have more fat there covering them.

Comment: It got closed for a duplicate so I can't answer. If you can see upper abs instead of lower abs, then it's a bodyfat issue.  You carry more bodyfat in the lower abs than the upper, so the only solution is to lose more bodyfat.